# Group user events into activity sessions

Tags: ruby, hash

You’re in charge of implementing a new analytics “sessions” view. You’re given a set of data that consists of individual web page visits, along with a visitorId which is generated by a tracking cookie that uniquely identifies each visitor. From this data we need to generate a list of sessions for each visitor.

The data set looks like this:

```
    "events": [
         {
             "url": "/pages/a-big-river",
             "visitorId": "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039",
             "timestamp": 1512754583000
         },
         {
             "url": "/pages/a-small-dog",
             "visitorId": "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039",
             "timestamp": 1512754631000
         },
        {
            "url": "/pages/a-big-talk",
            "visitorId": "f877b96c-9969-4abc-bbe2-54b17d030f8b",
            "timestamp": 1512709065294
        },
        {
            "url": "/pages/a-sad-story",
            "visitorId": "f877b96c-9969-4abc-bbe2-54b17d030f8b",
            "timestamp": 1512711000000
        },
        {
            "url": "/pages/a-big-river",
            "visitorId": "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039",
            "timestamp": 1512754436000
        },
        {
            "url": "/pages/a-sad-story",
            "visitorId": "f877b96c-9969-4abc-bbe2-54b17d030f8b",
            "timestamp": 1512709024000
        }
    ]
}
```

Given this input data, we want to create a set of sessions of the incoming data. A sessions is defined as a group of events from a single visitor with no more than 10 minutes between each consecutive event. A visitor can have multiple sessions. So given the example input data above, we would expect output which looks like:

```
{
    "sessionsByUser": {
        "f877b96c-9969-4abc-bbe2-54b17d030f8b": [
            {
                "duration": 41294,
                "pages": [
                    "/pages/a-sad-story",
                    "/pages/a-big-talk"
                ],
                "startTime": 1512709024000
            },
            {
                "duration": 0,
                "pages": [
                    "/pages/a-sad-story"
                ],
                "startTime": 1512711000000
            }
        ],
        "d1177368-2310-11e8-9e2a-9b860a0d9039": [
            {
                "duration": 195000,
                "pages": [
                    "/pages/a-big-river",
                    "/pages/a-big-river",
                    "/pages/a-small-dog"
                ],
                "startTime": 1512754436000
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Notes

- Timestamps are in milliseconds.
- Events may not be given in chronological order.
- The visitors in sessionsByUser can be in any order.
- For each visitor, sessions to be in chronological order.
- For each session, the URLs should be sorted in chronological order
- For a session with only one event the duration should be zero
- Each event in a session (except the first event) must have occurred
  within 10 minutes of the preceding event in the session. This means
  that there can be more than 10 minutes between the first and the last
  event in the session.

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I am not gonna show you how to make the exact output format you need, but I will show you the general approach for solving this problem, and hopefully you can figure out how to change it for your requirements.*

You are gonna want to start out by grouping the events by user:

```
events_by_user = events.group_by { |event| event[:visitorId] }
```

Now, for each user, you need to sort their events by timestamp:

```
events_by_user.transform_values! do |events|
  events.sort_by { |event| event[:timestamp] }
end
```

Now, you need to loop through each user's events and compare them in sequential order, putting them in groups based on timestamp similarity:

```
session_length = 10 # seconds

sessions = {}
events_by_user.each do |visitor_id, events|
  sessions[visitor_id] = []
  events.each do |event|
    if sessions[visitor_id].empty?
      sessions[visitor_id].push([event])
    else
      last_session = sessions[visitor_id].last
      last_timestamp = last_session.last[:timestamp]

      if (event[:timestamp] - last_timestamp) <= session_length
        last_session.push(event)
      else
        sessions[visitor_id].push([event])
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Now `sessions` will contain a hash like this:

```
{
    <visitor_id>: [
      [<list of events in session 1>],
      [<list of events in session 2>]
    ],
    etc.
}
```

You can then extract the start time, total duration, etc

Answer (score 0):

Group the "events" array by the property "visitorId" first. You can use in JavaScript the

> Array.prototype.reduce(): The reduce() method executes a user-supplied
> “reducer” callback function on each element of the array, in order,
> passing in the return value from the calculation on the preceding
> element. The final result of running the reducer across all elements
> of the array is a single value. So, set `{}` as the initial value for the reducer function, at each pass use the visitorId as key to an array that will hold events of the visitor, push the current event to respective position in the array.
>
> The  `a variable || []` statement is used to make an 'undefined'
> value as [], empty array.

Now sort the events array that is built just now by timestamp in ascending order.
Loop through it and compare timestamps pairwise (previous and current array element), if difference is below given session length(eg 10 min), merge the two sessions and push it in an array with 'visitorId' as key. Use a variable to keep track of the index of the session to be merged together.

```
let data = require('d:\\dataset.json');

//Group by visitorId
let sessions = {
    sessionsByUser: data.events.reduce(function (events, session) {
        (events[session['visitorId']] = events[session['visitorId']] || []).push(session);
        return events;
    }, {})
};


//Sort events by timestamp ascending
for(let key in sessions.sessionsByUser){
    let events = sessions.sessionsByUser[key];
    events = events.sort((a, b) => {
        return a.timestamp - b.timestamp;
    });
}

let userSessions = {};
for(let key in sessions.sessionsByUser){
    let events = sessions.sessionsByUser[key];
    let lastIndex = 0;
    for(let i = 0; i < events.length; i++)
    {
        
        if(i == 0) {
            userSessions[key] = [{
                duration: 0,
                pages: [events[i].url],
                startTime: events[i].timestamp
                
            }]
        }
        else {
            //Check difference (10 min)
            if(events[i].timestamp - events[i-1].timestamp < 600000) {
                let session = userSessions[key][lastIndex];
                session.duration += (events[i].timestamp - events[i-1].timestamp);
                session.pages.push(events[i].url);
            }
            else {
                userSessions[key].push({
                    duration: 0,
                    pages: [events[i].url],
                    startTime: events[i].timestamp
                   
                });
                lastIndex++;
            }
        }
    }
}

let soln = {
    sessionsByUser: userSessions
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(soln));

Run command in cmd: Node <filename>.js
```

> Change dataset path, navigate to the directory of the file in cmd. Node must
> be installed on the system.